# Help with Test Coverage for aggregate function query

Tags: apex, code-coverage, aggregateresult

Hoping someone will be able to help me. I have come most of the way in trying to implement some code, but I have hit a road block. I am sitting right now at 66% code coverage, and I want to understand how to up this to at least 75%, if not 100%. I have been doing research for the last day and have made it this far, but I cannot find anything that else helpful on the subject. My class is:

```
public class janFebPromos {


 private final Account acct;
 Public list<AggregateResult> jfprom;
 public janFebPromos(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
 this.acct = [select id, name from Account where id=:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
jfprom = [select report_description__c RDesc, SUM(qty_shipped__c) Quantity, SUM(Total_Sale_Amount__c) Total 
            from invitem__c 
            where cust_num__c = :this.acct.Id
            and sales_cat__c = 'PROM' 
            and inv_date__c >= 2016-12-15 
            and inv_date__c <= 2017-02-14 
            Group by report_description__c];
 }
public list<AggregateResult> jfpromlist {
get { return jfprom;}
}

}
```

And here is my test class so far:

```
@isTest
public class janFebPromosTest {
@isTest static void janFebPromosTest(){
    Account acct = new Account(Name='Test');
    invoice__c inv = new invoice__c(inv_num__c='123215654621');
    insert acct;
    insert inv;

    List<invitem__c> testILI = new List<invitem__c>();
    for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
        invitem__C o = new invitem__c();
        o.Ext_Id__c=String.valueOf(1234+i);          
        o.inv_date__c=date.valueOf('2017-01-01');
        o.cust_num__c= acct.id;
        o.inv_num__c=inv.Id;
        o.sales_cat__c=string.valueOf('PROM');
        o.report_description__c=string.valueof('1 test');
        o.qty_shipped__c=decimal.valueof('5');
        testILI.add(o);
    }
    insert testILI;

    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',acct.Id);
    ApexPages.StandardController std = new ApexPages.StandardController(acct);
    janFebPromos ace = new janFebPromos(std);

}

}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not even using `acct` variable anywhere, if required declare it inside the constructor.

---

Following line would give `List has no row of assignment error` when a valid Id is not passed in URL or if empty.

Use `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')` directly inside the query.

---

Your test method doesn't even has any asserts, apart from coverage add as much as meaningful asserts possible.

Adding a psuedo test code for you, important is to call the property `jfpromlist` which would cover it. Do not forget to validate the result by adding appropriate asserts.

```
@isTest public class janFebPromosTest {
    @isTest static void janFebPromosTest(){

        // your test data creation
        //**** Use asserts to verify your test data is been created, NEVER assume!

        // start actual testing inside Start and stop test
        Test.startTest();

        // calling controller method
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',acct.Id);
        ApexPages.StandardController std = new ApexPages.StandardController(acct);
        janFebPromos ace = new janFebPromos(std);

        // fetch the list of aggregate result from controller's instance
        List<AggregateResult> jfpromlist = ace.jfpromlist;

        // assert your result
        System.assertEquals('your condition',
            jfpromlist);

        Test.stopTest;
    }

}
```

Comment: your suggestions are wonderful I really appreciate your help! I am still in the early stages of learning Apex, can you please explain what the 'your condition' mean in the final 'System.assertEquals()'? I have been trying to pin it down, but have been unable to when it comes to a list of results.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) trailhead module. Its pretty much extensive. In short, asserts are used to validate if you're getting expected data  as if you were testing it manually.

Comment: Cool, I really appreciate it, Rahul!